# Stack Overflow's favicon is missing in Google Search results, but it shows for other SE sites

Tags: bug, google, favicon

For the past few days, I have noticed Google Search results no longer show stackoverflow.com's favicon/shortcut-icon in search results, but other SE sites (including Meta) are shown with them.

This could be a bug/issue with stackoverflow.com's icon file or `<meta />` reference - <sub>or (somewhat conspiratorily) it *could* be Google "punishing" Stack Exchange *for something*, I guess</sub>.

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: Yep, that's the exact behavior in my case too. Maybe Google didn't like the new Microsoft Azure collective ;)

Comment: I just noticed this too. It made me skip the first result for a second because I thought it was a google ad.

Comment: GitHub's favicon was also not showing. Looks like both are back now.

Answer (score 6):

The issue seems to have resolved itself sometime this week - as the favicons now appear fine in Google Search:

(I typed-in a nonsensical search query into Google and (and I *swear* it's unintentional) but Google decided to use its LLM AI to generate a *very incorrect* answer which I just find most amusing, so I'm leaving it in the screenshot for posterity, while the favicon is visible at the bottom)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to this so that it helps with debugging the problem, Stack Overflow has a few [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) errors when I visit it. A lot of them are regarding image requests from Imgur, and perhaps that may have something to do with this problem.

[image]

Comment: CORS errors wouldn't cause this issue.

Comment: I thought this may have something to do with CORS in case SO had two icons loading up, one for the favicon to show on Google and one for the site itself (I don't exactly know how these icons and SEO work, but just a guess), so thought this answer might be relevant. And then again, there were a lot of images from Imgur showing the CORS error so it increased my suspicion more. I can still delete this answer if you guys are sure this absolutely cannot not be the case.